# Java | Apache Commons CSV | How can i write a csv file with utf-8-bom?

Tags: java, maven, csv, byte-order-mark

I want to write a csv file in Excel format (utf-8-bom) with the apache.commons.csv and the apache.commons.io. It have only a BOMInputStream method.
It is a little paradox but i can't find any howto's for writing csv files in utf-8-bom for Excel.

Is it possible with java to write files with the BOM-coding?
Have anybody a idea to make this? Thanks for help!

Comment: Just write the character BOM. Your encoder (when you are saving the file) will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding header to CSV, simplest solution is to prefix first column header with BOM bytes:

```
public static final String UTF8_BOM = new String(new byte[] {(byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xBF},StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
//...
String[] header = new String[2];
header[0] = UTF8_BOM + "column1";
header[1] = "column2";
final CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withDelimiter(';').withHeader(header);
try(FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFormat);){
    //write CSV data ...
}
```

This way you can use one 'try with resources' without caring when CSVPrinter prints header. Otherwise you have to make sure to write BOM before CSVPrinter writes header.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is delt with in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom). In general BOM is allowed but neither needed nor recommended in UTF-8. So all you need is to write a file in UTF-8. For details see the link to the question that deals with this issue

Comment: In general yes, but opening a CSV in Excel needs the BOM to recognize UTF-8 content...